# Css grid IE 11 : Autoprefixeur online vs package npm

Tags: webpack, internet-explorer-11, css-grid, autoprefixer

I am using Css Grid and i have some issues with autoprefixer. I pay attention to respect some conditions when using it with IE. This is a part of the sass :

```css
 .wrapper-bloc-horaire {

      /*! autoprefixer grid: autoplace */
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 65px minmax(30%, max-content) minmax(30%,max-content);
      grid-template-rows: 30px 25px;
      grid-template-areas: "image titre titre"
                            "image depart arrive";
      grid-column-gap: 2rem;


      div:first-of-type {
        grid-area: image;
      
        place-self: center;
      }

      .s-title4 {
        grid-area: titre;
       
      }

      .resume-line:nth-of-type(2) {
        grid-area: depart;
      }
      .resume-line:nth-of-type(3) {
        grid-area: arrive;
      }
}
```

My webpack config :

```
use: [
                { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                        url: false,
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: "postcss-loader",
                    options: {
                        postcssOptions: {
                            plugins: [
                                [
                                'autoprefixer',
                                ],
                            ],
                        },
                    }
                },
                "sass-loader"
            ],
```

My broswerlist :

```
"browserslist": ["> 1%","IE 11"]
```

When i'm running webpack with that config, only ...

```
display:-ms-grid;
display:grid;
-ms-grid-columns:65px 2rem minmax(30%,max-content) 2rem minmax(30%,max-content);
grid-template-columns:65px minmax(30%,max-content) minmax(30%,max-content);
-ms-grid-rows:30px 25px;grid-template-rows:30px 25px;
```

... is prefixed.
But when i try [autoprefixer online](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) everything works well with the good output :

```
.wrapper-bloc-horaire{
 display:-ms-grid;
 display:grid;
 -ms-grid-columns:65px 2rem minmax(30%,max-content) 2rem minmax(30%,max-content);
 grid-template-columns:65px minmax(30%,-webkit-max-content) minmax(30%,-webkit-max-content);
 grid-template-columns:65px minmax(30%,max-content) minmax(30%,max-content);
 -ms-grid-rows:30px 25px;
 grid-template-rows:30px 25px;
 grid-template-areas:"image titre titre" "image depart arrive";
 grid-column-gap:2rem
}
.block-resume-container .wrapper-bloc-horaire [class$=col1]{
  -ms-grid-row:1;
  -ms-grid-row-span:2;
  -ms-grid-column:1;
  grid-area:image;
  -ms-grid-row-align:center;
  -ms-grid-column-align:center;
  place-self:center
}
.block-resume-container .wrapper-bloc-horaire .s-title4{
  -ms-grid-row:1;
  -ms-grid-column:3;
  -ms-grid-column-span:3;
  grid-area:titre
}
.block-resume-container .wrapper-bloc-horaire .resume-line:nth-of-type(2){
  -ms-grid-row:2;
  -ms-grid-column:3;
  grid-area:depart
}
.block-resume-container .wrapper-bloc-horaire .resume-line:nth-of-type(3){
  -ms-grid-row:2;
  -ms-grid-column:5;
  grid-area:arrive
}
```

Do you know why autoprefixer does not work properly ?
Thank you !

Comment: And by any chance there should be such a record? `autoprefixer({ grid: "autoplace" })`

Comment: I wrote " /*! autoprefixer grid: autoplace */  " to make sure that grid is activated.

Comment: It seems that it should be `/* autoprefixer grid: autoplace */`, not `/*! autoprefixer grid: autoplace */`. You can check [the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer#grid-autoplacement-support-in-ie) about this.

Comment: I use cssnano as well and it runs before autoprefixer so if i don't add `/*!` , this comment is deleted and autoprefixer don't see it.

Comment: Nobody knows ? :(